# How to find the first occurrence of duplication and transform that to text

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

My script file has the following content:

```
grep -i apple basket.*
grep -i apple basket.*
grep -i lion zoo.*
grep -i lion zoo.*
```

I'd like to have the following content instead:

```
echo "Finding apple in basket.*"
grep -i apple basket.*
echo "Finding lion in zoo.*"
grep -i lion zoo.*
```

Essentially I'd like to find duplication in my script file, catch the first occurence of duplication, and transform only that first occurrence into text.

Is this possible and if so, how can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/grep -i //; s/(.*) (.*)/echo "Finding \1 in \2"/; N' file
```

or

```
sed -E 's/grep -i (.*) (.*)/echo "Finding \1 in \2"/; N' file
```

> N: append the next line of input into the pattern space

Output:

```
echo "Finding apple in basket.*"
grep -i apple basket.*
echo "Finding lion in zoo.*"
grep -i lion zoo.*
```